# Key-Binding for a Custom Eclipse Content Assist

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, key-bindings, content-assist

I've implemented a content assist proposal computer as an eclipse plugin (using `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.javaCompletionProposalComputer`). I would now like to bind it to it's own key combination (otherwise the custom proposals appear at the bottom of the proposal list).

I tried doing this by extending `org.eclipse.ui.bindings`, but this requires defining `org.eclipse.ui.commands`, a `handler`, and possibly more things.

It seems that there is already a command created for my custom content assist computer, since it appears under the key binding menu (in `Windows->Preferences->Keys`), but I don't know what is the id of this command. If that command is created at runtime, then can I even refer to its `commandId` in my plugin.xml?

Is there another, simpler way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After experimenting with many different ways of implementing this I found that:

1) The command associated with custom completion proposal computers is `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.specific_content_assist.command`, and it is defined in the `plugin.xml` of the `org.eclipse.jdt.ui` plugin (provided by eclipse).

2) This is a parametrized command, which means it takes a commandParameter with `id=org.eclipse.jdt.ui.specific_content_assist.category_id`. The value of this parameter should be the id of the `proposalCategory` for your `javaCompletionProposalComputer`.

Here's an example of how I defined custom key-binding:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">   
    <key
        sequence="CTRL+ALT+SPACE"
        contextId="org.eclipse.ui.contexts.dialogAndWindow"
        schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"
        commandId="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.specific_content_assist.command">
        <parameter
            id="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.specific_content_assist.category_id"
            value="YOUR_PROPOSAL_CATEGORY_GOES_HERE"/>
    </key>
</extension>
```

No need to define a new command or handler!