# ClassNotFoundException when instantiating an eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, classpath, classnotfoundexception

I developed an eclipse plugin and I'm trying to install it on another instance of eclipse.
When I run/debug my plugin as an eclipse application everything works correctly. The problem occurs only after I install the plugin through the update site I created.

I created a very simple update site which includes a single feature with my plugin packaged in it. After installing using the update site I can see my plugin in the `plugin` directory under the eclipse install dir and it correctly contains all the data that should be in there (I think). However, when I instantiate the plugin (by hitting the key-binding I defined) I get a ClassNotFoundException for the main plugin class, one that I created and that can be found in the `bin` directory of my plugin.

It seems that the `bin` directory is somehow not recognized as a place to search for classes, but I assume that it should be added to the eclipse classpath as part of the plugin installation.

I googled quite a bit about this and found many related problems, none of which was quite hitting my specific situation. I would appreciate any suggestion!

Comment: How are you defining the key binding? Is this in the plugin.xml or somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, I'm defining it through the plugin.xml. There are some details about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18519534/key-binding-for-a-custom-eclipse-content-assist/18601197#18601197

Comment: Have you added the package containing the `javaCompletionProposalComputer` to the `Export-Package` list in the `MANIFEST.MF` so that the jdt plugin can find it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. Do I need to create a package/jar with the class files? They are already there under the `bin` directory of the plugin. I assumed that this is where eclipse would search for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a plugin other plugins can only access the classes in packages declared in the Export-Package section of the Manifest.mf. Open the plugin.xml editor and look at the 'Runtime' tab - it needs to have your package listed. Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. In my case things look slightly different than in your screenshot, but I basically had to add my `bin` directory to the runtime classpath. Pretty strange that this isn't being done by default, but hey, at least it's working now :)