# Classpath and plug-in dependencies in Java Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, classpath

I have got a `Java` Maven project in Eclipse which imports some external plug-ins for which I do not have the source code.
One of those plug-ins should be able to access some of the public classes from my project. The package/class name can be defined dynamically.

After some research I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18644482/classnotfoundexception-when-instantiating-an-eclipse-plugin) thread which says, that exported packages should be visible to other plug-ins. But unfortunately this does not work in my case.

Does anybody have any idea how I could give the imported plugin access to my classes?
Thanks!

Comment: Exported packages are visible to other plugins which include the plugin in their dependencies - have you done that?

Comment: @greg-449 Okay that makes sense. But if I go to the Dependencies tab of the imported plug-in, the Add... button is greyed out. Do I have to add this manually (in text) to the manifest file?

Comment: This might be relevant: the imported plug-in is not my own plug-in!

Comment: How do you expect this plugin to use your classes even if it could access them?

Comment: @greg-449 I am only accessing static functions. I actually am able to get it to work if I put the plug-in's jar file on the Classpath (in the manifest Runtime tab). But this is not the way I would like to do it.

Comment: If the plugin exports the packages containing the static functions you can use them by adding the plugin to your plugin's dependencies. If it does not export the packages you can't use them.

Comment: @greg-449 I don't know if I understand correctly. What I would have to do: 1.) export package 2.) add my OWN plugin to the dependencies of the IMPORTED plugin? How can I modify the dependencies of the imported plugin?